# Duvidas Intel XDK

Tags: intel-xdk

Bom estou precisando identificar se a linguagem XDK da Intel, tem funcionalidades onde ela roda sem a utilização da internet ? Ou todo conteúdo para visualizar e utilizar é necessário a conexão com a internet ?

O motivo para que eu preciso é criar um aplicativo que mesmo que a pessoa esteja offline ela consiga trabalhar em modo offline com o aplicativo, e ao conectar todo o trabalho comitado seria salvo no banco de dados ?

O Intel XDK me possibilita isto ?
O Intel XDK é uma linguagem compilada ?
Tenho possibilidade de utilizar banco de dados internos no intel xdk ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não sei se podemos chamar o xdk de linguagem de programação, na descrição da meta aqui no stack diz :

> O Intel® XDK é uma ferramenta de desenvolvimento para aplicativos web e híbrido baseado em HTML5.

Acredito que seja uma IDE para desenvolvimento hibrido, mas tem algumas coisas próprias que trabalham em cima do cordova. Eu utilizo para trabalhar com angular + cordova + javascript + ionic.

Não é necessário o usuário se conectar com a internet. Apenas no emulador você vai precisar estar conectado para testar, mas quando gerar o apk e instalar no aparelho vai poder fazer sim da forma que imaginou ai, o usuário conseguir rodar o app sem problemas. 
Tudo que é possivel fazer com angular, cordova ou qualquer framework que você for utilizar você pode fazer nele. Eu geralmente produzo os apps no Netbeans e uso o XDK para testar,configurar, debugar ou fazer o build dos apps.

Comment: OBRIGADO PELA RESPOSTA PORÉM É UMA QUESTÃO ANTIGA ONDE EU COM ESTUDO E ENTUSIASMO ME TORNEI PARTNER DA INTEL ALÉM DE TRABALHAR COM O PROGRAMA. HOJE MEUS APLICATIVOS SÃO HÍBRIDOS TAMBÉM QUANDO SE DIZ ONLINE/OFFLINE POIS DOU A CHANCE DO USUÁRIO TER EXPERIÊNCIAS DAS DUAS FORMAS NA MESMA APLICAÇÃO.